# Encryption with substitution cipher

Tags: c++, string, c++14

I am replacing each letter of the alphabet with another letter of the alphabet.
For example, each 'a' gets replaced with a 'Q', and every 'b' gets replaced with a 'W'.
I have written code to encrypt the sentence bellow.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cctype>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string alphabet {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
    string key      {"QWERTYUIOPasdfghjklZXCVBNMqwertyuiopASDFGHJKLzxcvbnm"};

    string original {};
    string encrypted {};

    cout<<"Enter your secret message: ";
    getline(cin ,original);
    // cout<<"Encrypting message..."<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<original.length();i++){
        if(isalpha(original.at(i)) == 1){
            encrypted.at(i) =  key.at(alphabet.find(original.at(i)));
        }
        else
            encrypted.at(i) = original.at(i);
    }

    cout<<"Encrypted message: "<<encrypted<<endl;
}
```

I am changing each char with index i in string alphabets with char of the same index from key.
For example:- If Original string = "Hello"
              encrypted string should be "iTssg"

But when i run this program i am getting an error

Output:
Enter your secret message: Hello
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)

Can anyone tell me what changes should I make in this code?

Comment: You should explore the use of `std::unordered_map` here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `encrypted` string is empty, so indexing into it with `.at()` throws an exception.

To solve this problem, you could append the characters, like this:

```
 for(int i=0;i<original.length();i++){
        if(std::isalpha(original.at(i))){
           encrypted +=  key.at(alphabet.find(original.at(i)));
        }
        else 
           encrypted += original.at(i);
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/khvP8n).

Alternatively, you could ensure that `encrypted` has the same size as `original`, like this:

```
encrypted = original;
```

and then your loop stays the same.

Also, you could simplify your loop, by using a range-for loop:

```
for(unsigned char c : original){
        if(std::isalpha(c)){
            encrypted +=  key.at(alphabet.find(c));
        }
        else
            encrypted += c;
    }
```

You could simplify this even further by combining the 2 approaches:

```
string encrypted = original;
for (auto &c : encrypted)
  if (std::isalpha(c))
    c = key.at(alphabet.find(c));
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fK5Y7q).

Comment: But if replace the first code you mentioned it is throwing same error

Comment: What string(line of code) do you get the error for? Can't be for `encrypted`.

Comment: Also, the result of `isalpha` shouldn't be compared to `1`. I've fixed that in the answer.

Comment: No worries. Added an even simpler solution to the answer.